# Enlarge height of a div using jquery and $('div').css: transition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I am currently setting up my homepage, and I am making some collapsible-boxes for a better structure.
The collapsible-boxes were created with pure CSS and HTML, but when a collapsible is activated, (obviously) the div-element where collapsible is, has also to be made bigger (changing height).

To achive this, I use jquery and came up with the following (this is just a fast/small example to demonstrate the problem):

```js
$(function() {

  var height_content = $("#content").height();

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

      $('#content').css({
        'height': height_content + 700 + 'px',
      });

      height_content = $("#content").height();
      console.log(height_content);
    } else {

      $('#content').css({
        'height': height_content - 700 + 'px',
      });

      height_content = $("#content").height();
      console.log(height_content);
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #content {
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto
    }
    
    #footer {
      border: 1px solid green;
      height: 50px;
      width: 200px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <input id="btn" type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>Footnote</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And it works, when I am clicking on the checkbox the content div is made bigger. Now, since it looked very static I decided to include a `transition-element for smoothness like this:

```
...

if($(this).is(':checked')) {
$('#content').css({
   'height': height_content + 700 + 'px',
   'transition': 'height 0.5s'
 });

 ...

 else {
 $('#content').css({
    'height': height_content - 700 + 'px',
    'transition': 'height 0.5s'
 });

 ...
```

But now the height-element plays weird, and expands it to different false sizes. The Log of a right expandable-process looks like this:

```
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
test.html:26 900
test.html:36 200
```

With the transition-option I get this log:

```
test.html:26 200
test.html:36 900
test.html:26 0
test.html:36 1600
test.html:26 0
test.html:36 2300
test.html:26 0.484375
test.html:36 2995.36
test.html:26 4.60938
test.html:36 3695.36
test.html:26 0
test.html:36 4388.78
test.html:26 0
test.html:36 5087.64
test.html:26 0
test.html:36 5786.27
test.html:26 0
test.html:36 6486.27
test.html:26 0
test.html:36 7186.27
test.html:26 10.4062
test.html:36 7886.27
test.html:26 0
```

Has anyone an idea, how I can fix this?

Comment: Yeah, in your `else` you have it still adding height `'height': height_content + 700 + 'px',` Also, I don't know why you're adding the transition to your JS when you can put it in your CSS as `transition: height .5s ease;` on the `#content` div

Comment: oh snap that was a spelling mistake in the `else`, of course there is a `-`, just fixed it. I will try adding id directly in CSS, didn't think of that thanks for the suggestion!
**edit:** putting `transition` directly in CSS `#content` gives the same output..

Comment: If you look at the _bad_ output, you can see it's adding 700px every time you click on it.